# Design for a shop - multiple product classes

Tags: java, design-patterns

I was reading about Spring and encountered an example consisting of an abstract product class with `name` and `price` fields.

Next, there is a `Battery` class which extends the `Product` class and adds a `rechargable` field. Then, a `CDDrive` class (also) extending `Product` but adding a `capacity` field.

In the real world when we often have products having many disparate attributes, how does one model arbitrary products with arbitrary properties and fields? 
Does having a class for each product make sense?

So, can you guys please suggest a pattern for achieving this?

Thanks,
Ouney

Comment: Thanks @ElliottFrisch - I have taken out that part of code as it was overpowering the actual question i have. Can you please look at it now?

Comment: *Does having a class for each product make sense?* In most real world cases, you would have very few subclasses of `Product` as different products will normally be differentiated by different *properties*, (e.g. the name property will be "Battery" instead of "CD Drive").  That's because most shop software will not behave fundamentally different when you're buying a battery than when you're buying a CD drive.  Further, you want to be able to add products by changing the *data*, rather than having to deploy new code.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - My intention here was to learn something new about design pattern. I thought that it can be implemented gracefully using some design pattern in java. I just sought an opportunity to learn something new about java design pattern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question. We had a similar situation before where we had GUI components that shared many of their abstract parent, but each page had its own set of labels that weren't shared by others. The standoff was on. We found it silly to just keep creating subclasses because of the mutually disjoint properties they had. What did it for us was maps. First, to have a subclass is to have one or more distinguishing properties that are fist class objects. Rechargeable for batteries and capacity for cd drives in your case. Then for the properties one can't think of at the time of building, or simply differ in minor naming conventions, use maps. I demonstrate with the example below.

The product:

```
public abstract class Product {
 String name;
 Double price;
 Map<String, Object> propMap;

 public Product(String name, Double price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    propMap = new HashMap<>();
 }

 public void add2propMap(String key, Object value) {
    propMap.put(key, value);
 }

 public String toString() {
    return "Product [name=" + name + ", price=" + price + ", propMap=" + propMap + "]";
 }
}
```

The CdDrive:

```
public class CdDrive extends Product {

String capacity;

public CdDrive(String name, Double price, String capacity) {
    super(name, price);
    this.capacity = capacity;
}
```

}

The Battery:

```
public class Battery extends Product {

Boolean rechargable;

public Battery(String name, Double price, Boolean rechargable) {
    super(name, price);
    this.rechargable = rechargable;
}
```

}

Then a client:

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

    Battery energizer = new Battery("Energizer", 12d, true);
    energizer.add2propMap("numInPackage", new Integer(8));
    energizer.add2propMap("make", "US");
    productList.add(energizer);

    CdDrive superDrive = new CdDrive("Apple Drive", 200d, "200 GB");
    superDrive.add2propMap("type", "External");
    superDrive.add2propMap("expandable", false);
    productList.add(superDrive);

    productList.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p));
}
```

}

Which gives this when run:

```
Product [name=Energizer, price=12.0, propMap={numInPackage=8, make=US}]
Product [name=Apple Drive, price=200.0, propMap={expandable=false, type=External}]
```

This setup made the architecture scalable, maintainable and modifiable. The map keys always reported what was in there in case in doubt. Adding is easy and so is modifying.

Comment: Thank you @mohsenmadi ...But still the situation is same in my case :). I will have to still create a separate class for each new product added. What you did can get rid of defining multiple properties in the class (not the classes itself). Does it make sense to have a class with attributes (name,price,type,properties) where type would be an enum containing values like Battery, CDDrive. But this does not seem to be a good oo design.

Comment: That's why I said: "First, to have a subclass is to have one or more distinguishing properties that are fist class objects". True, in the example (superficial, but illustrative) I gave up there there is no reason in not treating the distinguishing properties (rechargeable and capacity) as map properties too, I just left them as examples of "what if you badly needed subclasses". True, it is not OO design, but it's a design that serves the purpose of the scenarios at hand. Enforcing OO on the not OO'able is the superficial thing to do in this case. @Adrian Shum is highlighting the same here.

Comment: @mohsenmadi You should avoid using `wrapper` types such as `Boolean` and `Double` and use primitives instead. There are situations that warrant the use of wrappers over primitives but this is not one of them.

Comment: Agreed. I used wrappers here because the objects represented would end up in a map of objects, and boxing and unboxing would occur anyway. But... I wished that the focus here was on the main thesis of the post.

Answer (score 1):

> Does having a class for each product make sense?

In real life situation, it rarely makes sense.  They are just making up some example to make you get the feeling of it.

Just imagine your online shop sells CD players, now you want to add some MD players in your product list, and you need to change your code and redeploy the application just because of it.  Non-sense huh?

Unless you have bunch of specific function for some specific type of product, having a dedicated class for such type of product will make sense. (e.g. Product, PhysicallyDeliverableProduct something like that.  Still there are better way to design it though)

In real life, the way to solve the issue in your question, is mostly by designing your Product to keep some arbitrary properties (e.g. keeping a `Map<String,Object>`, so you can put `["rechargeable", true]` for a battery you add on your site.

Design pattern? I think what you are looking for is still far from required to make use of patterns. Personally I will suggest you to take a look on the book "Analysis Pattern" by Martin Fowler.  You may not be able to use the design in it directly, but it give you feel on what real life design looks like

Comment: Thanks @Adrian Shum - You mentioned "Still there are better way to design it though". Can you please suggest one or two of your ideas as i do see a scope here :)

Comment: It highly depends on what you need to achieve. Without proper context it is hard to suggest. For that poor example I gave, better way may be making PhysicalDeliverable an interface.

Answer (score 0):

> Does having a class for each product make sense?

To me it absolutely makes sense to have separate classes for separate products.
That makes your code more loosely coupled. In future if you want to change the implementation of a particular product, changing the code won't mess up the implementation of other products if you have a separate class for that. The generic methods & properties you can put in an abstract class.

> a pattern for achieving this?

You might want to look at the [Factory](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) & [template pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/template_pattern.htm).

You can create an interface Product & all the classes will implement that interface & define their own implementations.

Use abstract class only when you want to provide a default behaviour to your methods. For an instance have a look at the [template pattern here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/template_pattern.htm).

An abstract class game is created which defines the `play` method. `initialize` & `startPlay` etc can have their respective definition in the subclasses but the `play` method will always run the other methods.

```
public abstract class Game {
   abstract void initialize();
   abstract void startPlay();
   abstract void endPlay();

   //template method
   public final void play(){

      //initialize the game
      initialize();

      //start game
      startPlay();

      //end game
      endPlay();
   }
}
```

If you don't intend to provide any default behaviour rather just declare the properties & methods in an interface Product & let the classes implement that.

```
interface Product{
String NAME="defaultName";
Integer PRICE=5;
initialCost(); // example of a generic method
}

//Note that name & price if you declare those in interface will be treated as constants.

class Battery implements Product{
 Boolean rechargable =false; 
 public void initialCost(){
 //method definition
}
}

class CdDrive implements Product{
 Integer capacity = xxxx;
 public void initialCost(){
 //CdDrive method definition
}
}
```

You can create the objects as

```
Product product = new Battery();
Product nextProduct = new CdDrive();
```

this makes your code loosely coupled. Also known as programming to an interface.

Comment: you have just repeated the question.

Comment: Are you nuts? Haven't you read what I wrote about the template pattern?. I suggested him a pattern for achieving what he wanted.

Comment: please read the question. Whatever you have written here has been mentioned in the question. So as per you If i have products like "Table", "Shoes", "Shirt" etc. each having different attributes (name and cost being common). I should create separate class for each product? That is what i do not want (mentioned in the question).

Comment: It's nowhere written that I do not want this. Please re-read the question